# powershell - get a single word out of a string

Tags: powershell

I have a string:

```
<UserInputs><UserInput Question="Groupname" Answer="&lt;Values Count=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;Value DisplayName=&quot;AllHummanresources&quot; Id=&quot;af05c5d3-2312-c897-8439-08979d4d0a49&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Values&gt;" Type="System.SupportingItem.PortalControl.InstancePicker" /><UserInput Question="Ausgabe" Answer="Namen" Type="richtext" /></UserInputs>
```

I want to trim the string to get as result "**AllHummanresources**". So I need the word between `DisplayName=&quot;` and `&quot;` .

How can I achieve this goal?
I did not find a fitting example in the net :(

greetings

Comment: This "string" seems to be from an XML-file structure... In that case there are way better techniques to access the value you are looking for.

Comment: And it's odd that `Answer=` another escaped xml string `<Values Count="1"><Value DisplayName="AllHummanresources" Id="af05c5d3-2312-c897-8439-08979d4d0a49" /></Values>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Select-String` Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1) along [with regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1#example-3--find-a-pattern-match).

```
$result = $your_string |  Select-String -Pattern "DisplayName=&quot;(.*?)&quot;"
```

If the match is successful you can [access the group by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Match_Groups)

```
Write-Host $result.Matches.Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: ok, thank you. 
how do I get my "source code" into a string?  There are some quotation marks i it what causes problems if I jsut do $your_string = "............."

Comment: @rolfderwolf Enclose your string within single quote...

Comment: yes, also that is a problem. I get $name

Success  : True

Name     : 1

Captures : {1}

Index    : 94

Length   : 6

Value    : AllHumanresources
    and not just AllHumanresources

Comment: @rolfderwolf It should be `$result.Matches.Groups[1].Value`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Or `$name.Value`

Comment: sorry, I am such a noob. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `-replace` operator so that you omit everything apart from that string.

`$string -replace '.+(?:DisplayName=&quot;)(.*?)&quot.+', '$1'`

Granted this is only as good as the consistency of your input string.